# are there 5x5 pixel grayscale fonts?

Tags: fonts, resource-recommendations, grayscale

I am trying to design a (or: use an existing) very low-res bitmap/pixel font. I only have little space, but am thinking about utilizing different brightness levels of the pixels.

I found this [post (stackexchange)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91478/a-font-thats-readable-with-a-5px-height) where various low-res pixel fonts with height of 5px are discussed. But each pixel is only on/off here - one bit colordepth.

Are there designs for (low bitdepth) grayscale fonts? Grayscale values could be used to "round" corners a little - at least to fake it. Like the antialiasing in computer graphics.

If anyone has designs or some useful links I would greatly appreciate this!

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: thank you :-) !

Comment: @Mensch try this https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DrxH.png

Comment: You can't 'round' a pixel. a pixel is square. What's your use-case for this?

Comment: @Tetsujin [A pixel is *not* a little square, a pixel is *not* a little square, a pixel is *not* a little square! (And a voxel is not a little cube)](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf)

Comment: @joojaa - you try rounding the corner of one then, in greyscale ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin But no one said anything about rounding pixel corners. The question mentions using lighter pixels to create an effect of rounding _letter shapes_, the same way that screen antialiasing uses different colours and opacities to create rounding effects.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Screen antialiasing uses lots & lots of pixels to control the apparent smoothing - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z7WG.png We're talking about a 5x5 square, as in the linked question.

Comment: @Tetsujin It’s obviously not going to look like proper antialiasing – in fact, I doubt it’ll really work at all – but it’s the same basic concept (except in monochrome), and it’s nothing to do with rounding individual pixels.

Comment: @Tetsujin That looks really nice actually! Though I guess this image was created by some algorithmic process, that's kind of what I am looking for. I would fix the pixel bright values in the font though. (or the font bitmaps)

Comment: @exocortex - That's actually my Mac & how it deals with system fonts at 14pt on a non-retina screen, then magnified in Photoshop & screenshot. It's not the font drawn that way, it's system antialising doing it 'live'. If you look at the on-screen version of Ilmari's font from the linked answer, you'll see that in order to display it legibly on-screen, the pixels have actually been doubled. The real size is a quarter of that - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZTkb.png The real font is teeeeny!